# Tomcat/jsp/servlet /web.xml issue

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, tomcat5.5

I am working on a project for school and am completely frustrated.  The project is to get a simple JSP/Servlet demo working on our personal websites and after probably 20+ hours of work I am still unsuccessful in getting this accomplished.  The really frustrating thing I've been given all the code and still can't really get this to work.  Well, that isn't totally true.  I have gotten it to work on my local tomcat server, but I can't replicate that magic on my personal website.  So, here is what I have.

First, the code.  This assignment consists of two classes for servlets and two jsps and a web.xml file.

Here is the first servlet called ControllerServlet.java

```
 package test;

    // Import the servlet classes
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;

    // Import the standard Java classes
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

     /**
    * Controller Servlet
    */
    public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
      private static String HELLO_JSP = "hello.jsp";
    private static String GOODBYE_JSP = "goodbye.jsp";
    private static String OTHER_JSP = "main.jsp";

     public void init() throws ServletException
    {
      // Typically initialize your request to page mappings here
    }

    public void service( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res ) throws     ServletException
    {
    try
     {
      // Get the path - this is our key to our Request map
      String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();

      // Find out what the user is requesting 
      String jsp = null; 
      if( pathInfo.equalsIgnoreCase( "/hello" ) )
      { 
        String name = req.getParameter( "name" );
        PersonBean person = new PersonBean( name );
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        session.setAttribute( "person", person );
        jsp = HELLO_JSP;
      }
      else if( pathInfo.equalsIgnoreCase( "/goodbye" ) )
      {
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        PersonBean person = ( PersonBean )session.getAttribute( "person" );
        req.setAttribute( "person", person );
        session.removeAttribute( "person" );
        jsp = GOODBYE_JSP;
      }
      else
      {
        jsp = OTHER_JSP;
      }

      // Foward the request to the jsp
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher( "/" + jsp );
      dispatcher.forward( req, res );
    }
    catch( IOException ioe )
    {
      throw new ServletException( ioe );
    }
    }
    }
```

Now the PersonBean.java:

```
package test;

 public class PersonBean implements java.io.Serializable
 {
 private String name;

public PersonBean()
{
}

public PersonBean( String name )
{
  this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
  return this.name;
}

public void setName( String name )
 {
  this.name = name;
}
}
```

Now the hello.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="test.PersonBean" scope="session" />


<HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" /></TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
  <P>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" /></P>
  <A HREF="goodbye">Goodbye</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And the goodbye.jsp

```
 <jsp:useBean id="person" class="test.PersonBean" scope="session" />

   <HTML>
     <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Good bye, <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" /></TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
      <P>Good bye, <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name" /></P>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Lastly my web xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>deploy</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>ControllerServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testing/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My web server's file manager has a folder called WEB-INF under the public_html section so in that file folder I placed the two jsps and the web xml file.  Under that was a preexisting folder called classes which I made a new folder in called test and in that folder placed the two class files.  I would think that going to mysite.com/testing/hello?name=Bradley would result in the correct thing happening, but unfortunately I get a 404 error saying that url testing/hello is not found.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why and can't make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The servlet class declaration in `web.xml` is wrong. You're put `ControllerServlet` in a package `test`. So the proper servlet class declaration should be:

```
<servlet-class>test.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
```

How you got it to work at local environment is beyond me. Perhaps the package was initially not there at all, or perhaps you removed the package from the servlet class declaration, or perhaps you've 2 servlet classes in both the default and `test` package.

---

**Update**: based on the code given as far (and assuming that you fixed the servlet declaration in `web.xml`), here's how the folder structure should look like:

```
public_html 
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- classes
 |    |    `-- test
 |    |         |-- ControllerServlet.class
 |    |         `-- PersonBean.class
 |    `-- web.xml
 |-- goodbye.jsp
 |-- hello.jsp
 `-- main.jsp
```

Comment: I looked at my code and it seems that that is constructed that way, isn't it?

Comment: Mark McLaren has edited your question to fix the wrong servlet class declaration himself..?? I've rolledback it. Doublecheck your *actual* `web.xml` file.

Comment: Okay, I will look at that shortly.  My web page cpanel is down currently, but as soon as it is back up I will check that.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the proper file tree. Hopefully it's clear enough. Note that those JSPs should not be in `/WEB-INF` folder. If they were in there, then you should have changed their paths in the servlet to prefix with `/WEB-INF`: `req.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/" + jsp );`

Comment: Okay, thanks that really helps.  We are still down, but this looks to be really helpful.  Also, on my local tomcat installation my class servlet thing was correct, so I don't know how it go so uncorrect on the way to the web.  I will let you know as soon as I can make the recommended changes and hopefully that will work.  Regardless, your help has been appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so I checked and my servlet was actually listed as test.ControllerServlet so I'm not sure why that was wrong.  I moved my jsp files to be in the right place and have the structure you have suggested now.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are the `.class` files at the proper location? Are you sure that you didn't accidently copy `.java` files instead? Do you have access to Tomcat logs? Can you open the JSP files in `public_html` individually? e.g. mysite.com/hello.jsp

Comment: If I go to mysite.com/testing/hello.jsp I get a blank screen with the title "Insert title here".  If I go to mysite.com/hello.jsp it work saves for the name part is null.  They are class files.  Maybe I assembled them incorrectly?  What I did was put them both in a folder and then ran this:  javac PersonBean.java ControllerServlet.java and they both compiled.  See anything fishy about that?

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound stupid, but can I get a little more clarification on this.  I just had these two files on my desktop and did this:  cd desktop - javac PersonBean.java ControllerServlet.java  - So, I should have had these in a folder called test?

Comment: Nevermind this. Do you have any chance to read server logs? That JSPs work is a good sign that changes in public folder are picked up. You could as quick test change the `<servlet-class>` in `web.xml` by `<jsp-file>/hello.jsp</jsp-file>` and check if you see hello.jsp by calling mysite.com/testing. If that doesn't happen then changes in `web.xml` are not picked up and the server likely needs a redeploy. Contact the professor/serveradmin.

Comment: Okay. The server is down so I will checking this soon.  This is web hosting that I got through interadvantage and access through cpanel?  It doesn't appear as though I have access to anything like logs.  If I did where would you find them?

Comment: Changing the servlet-class line to that does indeed work and I get the hello.jsp page.

Comment: Okay. That excludes the `web.xml` from being suspect. That the `<servlet-class>` fails can mean only 3 things: 1) the class is not present in the classpath. 2) loading the class failed due to an incompliance error. 3) constructing the servlet or calling `init()` failed with an exception. In your case, 1) and 3) can likely be excluded. Left over 2). What's the Java version of your host? 1.6? 1.5? What Java version have you used to compile the class? 1.6? Try one step lower. `javac -target 1.5 test/ControllerServlet.java`.

Comment: Good question.  I am actually using 1.5, but I did this anyway.  I also got the code for another servlet and javaced it.  I uploaded it and changed my web.xml and it worked.  Reuploading my two class files javaced with the 1.5 command didn't change anything.  I still get the 404 saying /testing/goodbye was not found on the server.

Comment: Okay, I think I must be doing something wrong.  I just changed my web.xml for the one that I know works from this: <url-pattern>/servlet/CSCC09HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern> to this: <url-pattern>/test/CSCC09HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern> and it ceased to work at the new address and I even restarted my tomcat install.  Why would this be?

Comment: Okay, I figured this out.  On my server, you have to have /servlet/whatever in the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Several things you say make me a little nervous about your questions.

- It common to use a build tool (e.g. Ant or Maven).  You do not mention what build tool you are using.
- It is usual to create a WAR file and deploy it to your application server (e.g. Tomcat).  Although possible, it is unusual to copy class files onto your application server by hand (if you did this I think you would need to restart Tomcat to recognise this new application).
- **public_html** does not sound like Tomcat, it sounds more like Apache.  Usually Tomcat web applications are found under a directory called **webapps**.

Your web application should consist of something like:

```
~webapps/deploy/WEB-INF/web.xml
~webapps/deploy/WEB-INF/classes/test/ControllerServlet.class
~webapps/deploy/WEB-INF/classes/test/PersonBean.class
~webapps/deploy/hello.jsp
~webapps/deploy/goodbye.jsp
~webapps/deploy/main.jsp
~webapps/deploy/index.jsp
```

Usually your war let us call it **deploy.war** (named after the display-name in your web.xml) would contain everything in the deploy directory above.  This WAR file would be deployed to Tomcat.  Deployment can be done by copying the WAR file into the webapps directory of Tomcat or by using the Tomcat Manager App.

**index.jsp** is usually the default landing page for web applications (you can change this in your web.xml).

Comment: As to `public_html`, this is typical for a Tomcat-per-user virtual host setup on most Universities. I'm by the way not sure if you can deploy a fullworthy WAR into it.

Comment: I agree with Balus.  What you are saying makes total sense on my local tomcat server, but I don't know how that translates.  I made a WAR file a while ago and tried to place it where I thought it should go, but nothing happened.  Also, there is a folder called "tomcat" that I placed the WAR file in and it expanded to be correct, but unfortunately still didn't work.

Comment: Apologies I have only seen public_html in relation to Apache static file hosting.